# Multiple of same result even with group by

Tags: sql, oracle

Alright so say I have a 'product_catalog', and 'orders' tables. Each order has the product_catalog_id as a foreign key. What I want to return as the query results is the product_code (name of the product associated with a specific product_catalog_id) + a count of how many of each product_code have been ordered.  That's easy enough with something like this (Oracle SQL):

```
SELECT pc.product_code,
COUNT(*) as count
FROM orders o
join product_catalog pc on pc.product_catalog_id = o.product_catalog_id
GROUP BY pc.product_code
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

but I also want to print various pieces of information from the order table such as total of all monthly charges for that product_code.  That would seem easy enough with something like this:

```
(o.monthly_base_charge*count(*)) as "Monthly Fee"
```

but the problem is that there have been various monthly fees for the same product_code over time.  If I add the above line in and add 'o.monthly_base_charge' to the group by statement, then it will print out a unique row for every variation of pricing for that product_code.  How do I get it to ignore those price variations and just add together every entry with that product code?

Comment: Have you tried `sum(o.monthly_base_charge) as "Monthly Fee"`?

Comment: sum seems to do the exact same thing in this case as  (o.monthly_base_charge*count(*)) as "Monthly Fee"

Comment: @halfbit yeah sorry that actually does work once I take out the monthly base charge from the group by statment.  Unfortunately I can't give you the check since it's just a comment :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear what you are asking.  My best guess is that you want the sum of the monthly base charge:

```
SELECT pc.product_code,
       COUNT(*) as count,
       sum(o.monthly_base_charge) as "Monthly Fee"
FROM orders o join
     product_catalog pc
     on pc.product_catalog_id = o.product_catalog_id
GROUP BY pc.product_code
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want.  What happens if you have two orders in the same month for the same product?

Comment: It's a monthly fee, but I don't need to do any arithmetic like 5 months since order so 5*number of that product*number of months since order.  All I am trying to calculate is current income from monthly charges.  So if there are 500 orders for a product in the db, regardless of when they are placed, I would do 500*the base charge.  If there were 200 of the product sold at 1 base charge, and 300 at another base charge, the formula would be (200*1st base charge for product)+(300*2nd base charge for product).  Is that clearer?

Comment: In other words, the cost for a specific order doesn't change over time, but certain orders for a product may have 1 price while others have another price.  Regardless of the price, I need them to all be added together and displayed on a row with the product_code.

Comment: Actually, yeah this does in fact work like I want after I removed them from the group by statement. Umm halfbit in the comments for the original post actually answered about 30 seconds before you, but that can't get a check so, here you go.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do something like this since SQL will not be able to know which monthly base charge to multiply by the count.

```
SELECT pc.product_code,
    COUNT(*) as count,
    (min(o.monthly_base_charge)*count(*)) as "Monthly Fee"
FROM orders o
join product_catalog pc on pc.product_catalog_id = o.product_catalog_id
GROUP BY pc.product_code
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Or you will need to add o.monthly_base_charge to the group by in order for sql to know how to determine the count()

```
GROUP BY pc.product_code, o.monthly_base_charge
```

Comment: Well I don't want the minimum, so I don't think that part will work.  Each order has a monthly charge associated with it.  I want every order with a certain product_code to have the value in that field added together and displayed in a row with the product code